# What are the benefits of pip and virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, pip

So everyone is telling me to use pip and virtualenv but no-one is able to
explain me how it is better than my current approach. The main reason
for people to use pip and virtualenv seems to be that everyone else is using it...

I'm sure there are very good reasons to use PIP and virtualenv but I haven't
been able to find them with Google. I'm hoping that someone from the
stackoverflow community will be able to explain them to me.

Here is how I currently organize my Django projects:

```
site/src/ : contains all python-only dependencies of my project

site/lib/ : contains symlinks to the python packages

site/[projectname]/ : contains all my project specific code
```

The entire site folder is check in my repository (yes, including all python-only dependencies such as django itself).

All non-python-only dependencies (PIL, psycopg2, ...) are documented in a README and installed at the system level (apt-get install ....)

For example, let's say I have a project name "projectfoo" that depends on
django-1.2.3, pygeoip-0.1.3 and psycopg2 I will have:

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/psycopg2

~/projects/foo/site : checkout of my repository
~/projects/foo/site/src/django-1.2.3
~/projects/foo/site/src/pygeoip-0.1.3
~/projects/foo/site/lib/django -> symlink to ../src/django-1.2.3/django
~/projects/foo/site/lib/pygeoip -> symlink to ../src/pygeoip-0.1.3/pygeoip
~/projects/foo/site/projectfoo/
```

Now how does this compare with PIP/virtualenv in practice?

**Deploying the project with my current approach**:

```
svn checkout https://myserver.com/svn/projectfoo/tags/1.0.0STABLE/site
```

**Deploying with PIP/virtualenv**:

```
wget https://myserver.com/svn/projectfoo/tags/1.0.0STABLE/projectfoo-requirements.txt
pip install -U -E projectfoo-venv -r projectfoo-requirements.txt
```

**Working on a project with my current approach**:

```
cd ~/projects/foo/site/projectfoo
export PYTHONPATH=.:..:../lib
./manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

**Working on a project with PIP/virtualenv**:

```
workon projectfoo
cd path/to/project
./manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

**Dealing with non-python-only dependencies**:

non-python-only dependencies would be handled the same way, there is no way I'm
going to use the `--no-site-packages` option of virtualenv and install a compiler
and all the build dependencies on my servers, I don't think anyone is actually
doing it anyway.

**Upgrading a python-only dependency with my current approach**:

I checkout/unzip the new version in src, remove the old one from src, update the
symlink in lib and commit. Now everyone else working on the project will get the update at
their next `svn up` or `git pull`. One thing that is not nice is that the old
folder in src will remains if it contains some pyc file in it, this can easily
be avoided by removing all pyc before updating your local copy.

**Upgrading a python-only dependency with PIP/virtualenv**:

You commit a new version of the requirements file, hopefully everyone working on the
project notice the new version when they update their local copy and they then
run `pip install -E projectfoo-venv -r requirements.txt`.

**Edit**: I remove the use of -U with pip, this is not needed with pip 8.2

**Edit**: The only advantage on pip/virtualenv over my current approach seems to be when you work on different projects requiring differents version of python. But
in my experience when you need different versions of python you also
need different versions of others system libraries (PIL, psycopg2, ...)
and virtualenv doesn't help with that (except if you're crazy enough to
use the --no-site-package option, and even then it's incomplete). The
only solution I can think of for that situation is using different virtual machines.

**So what am I missing? Can someone point me to a use case where PIP or virtualenv
would be better than what I'm doing?**

Comment: There is no reason to use -U when pip-installing from your requirements file (presuming your requirements are all version-pinned, which they should be). When asking pip to install a specific version, it will upgrade/downgrade to that version without -U. And without -U, the bug you link to is no longer relevant: only the needed dependencies are downloaded. Please update your question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, if pip is leaving old versions of things installed when you install newer versions, that either means you are using a very old version of pip (probably from an OS package? current version is 0.8.2), or something is wrong. In general pip uninstalls old versions before installing new ones.

Comment: Without -U I get the following error after increasing the version number of docutils from 0.6 to 0.7 in my requirements.txt:


    VersionConflict: (docutils 0.6 (/home/dsalvetti/projectfoo-test/lib/python2.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('docutils==0.7'))

With -U pip will upgrade docutils to 0.7 but it will also re-download and re-install all others dependencies. I'm using pip 0.3.1 (from Ubuntu Lucid), I'll try with a more recent version.

Comment: Ok with pip 8.2.0 I don't need to use -U and it will upgrade properly, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 19):

virtualenv really shines when you have a number of projects, and don't want them to all share the same Python installation.  For example, you could have two project with conflicting requirements.

Comment: Good point I can't support multiple version of python by just changing PYTHONPATH. But in my experience when I needed 2 differents versions of python it was because the 2 projects where running 2 differents version of the OS on production. In this case the python version is just one of the many system libraries that are different and I prefer using virtual machine to fully replicate the production OS.

Comment: One virtual machine per project is obviously even more isolated than one virtual environment per project, but also hideously more complex and expensive if you have many projects to juggle.

Answer (score 9):

*"All non-python-only dependencies (PIL, psycopg2, ...) are documented in a README and installed at the system level (apt-get install ....)"*

Then you can't have different dependencies for different projects, and not different versions of these dependencies for different projects.

One effect of that is that your local installs aren't accurately reflecting the production machines, so you may have problems in reproducing production bugs, for example.

And if you install system tools that need one version, you are forced to use that same version everywhere, which may break your projects.

Also, undeleting modules needs to be done on the system python level. Virtualenv means you can set up a python install to test things without polluting the system install.

I'd definitely recommend having a separate python for your projects, and using something that isolates even that Python from the projects, like virtualenv or zc.buildout.

PIP is only an easier way to install modules, that also helps you uninstall them.

*"there is no way I'm going to use the --no-site-packages option of virtualenv and install a compiler and all the build dependencies on my servers, I don't think anyone is actually doing it anyway."*

No, I use zc.buildout, but it amounts to much the same thing, but less work. ;)

Comment: Fair enough, when you need to use 2 differents version of python for 2 differents projects my current approach doesn't work. But I don't think virtualenv is really solving the issue either. As you pointed out this is a problem for any system tool, not just python and in this case I use different virtual machine to make sure I can fully replication production (except for the hardware).

Comment: @djoume: I'm not talking about different versions of Python, but different versions of the dependencies. I'll clarify this. Obviously, if you have one virtual machine per project, you don't need virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

**I follow the method you have suggested without pip/virtualenv for my usual projects.**
This allows me to put the packages in specific directory.

```
+ext
  |
  |------python packages
+source
  |
  |------ project code and packages
```

And usually in the startup script I update the PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH="";
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${workingdir}/path/to/ext";
```

This has the advantage of keeping the project and dependencies self-contained. I echo, your thoughts here.

**How ever, I find the use of virtualenv, when**

1. I have to experiment with `something new`.
2. Even better when I want to use `two different versions of package` and compare them.
3. Another use is where, I keep `different related packages that can be used across projects`.

Ex: **Documentation**: Some key packages, I have installed includes sphinx, pygraphwiz, nterworkX and some more visualization packages. I use it across projects and also keep it out of system level installation to keep it unpolluted.

**I would also like you to checkout : Yolk.** I find it nice in combination of pip/virtualenv.

You can list packages

```
yolk -l
Jinja2          - 2.5.5        - active 
Markdown        - 2.0.3        - active 
Pycco           - 0.1.2        - active 
......
```

And check out pypi updates.

```
yolk --show-updates
Pycco 0.1.2 (0.2.0)
Sphinx 1.0.4 (1.0.5)
pip 0.8.1 (0.8.2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and thanks for yolk, I didn't know about it and it seems pretty cool indeed. Could you elaborate on the "two different versions of package" use case? I totally get the other 2 and they make sense.

Answer (score 2):

### Deploying with PIP/virtualenv:

According to you:

> ```
> wget https://myserver.com/svn/projectfoo/tags/1.0.0STABLE/projectfoo-requirements.txt
> pip install -U -E projectfoo-venv -r projectfoo-requirements.txt
> ```

**What I do:** I also "freeze" packages but I do it with `pip` and `virtualenv` and check in the entire project; including the Python packages. So my deployment is exactly like yours:

```
svn checkout https://myserver.com/svn/projectfoo/tags/1.0.0STABLE/site
```

### Working on a project with PIP/virtualenv:

According to you:

> ```
> workon projectfoo
> cd path/to/project
> ./manage.py runserver 0:8000
> ```

**What I do:** Add a [postactivate hook](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/src/511994f15d58/README) like this:

```
$ cat bin/postactivate
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV
./manage.py runserver 0:8000
$
```

And now, to change to the project:

```
workon projectfoo
```

Comment: Are you saying that  you check in the entire virtual environment? That's interesting, I've never considered doing that. Doesn't this cause an issue if the virtualenv is not checkout at the same PATH?

Comment: Good catch. I'll be honest: I have only checked in and out of the same path on different machines. Perhaps that could be an issue but I wouldn't know at the moment. If it is a problem, I bet there's a way around it as well.